# Unknown request URI: /datastore

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using cloud datastore with my django 2.1 application. When I enter the localhost:8081, it gets me to the page saying ok. But when I type localhost:8081/datastore, it gives me following error.

> [datastore] INFO: Unknown request URI: /datastore

I am using datastore emulator. Please help.

Project level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('chaipani.urls')),
path('users/', include('chaipani.urls')),
path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('invitations/', include('invitations.urls', namespace='invitations')),
]
```

application level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),

]
```

My app.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: You really need to provide more details (and code) when you ask a question. Check [Ask] for some guidelines. In this case, what does your `urls.py` look like? How can I reproduce your issue?

Comment: I am sorry for that. I have updated.

Comment: So what makes you believe `/datastore` should lead to anything if you haven't defined it in your url patterns?

Comment: I am using datastore emulator. As localhost:8081 leads me to a page saying 'ok'. So I believe that datastore emulator must be having some underlying mechanism to view datastore.

Comment: I am new in all this stuff. Went through the docs and blogs. Couldn't find a way to see my data being updated/inserted in my datastore. So I am just curious about seeing my data.

Comment: Not sure about the port numbers you’re using. Where did you specify 8081? And are you using the new cloud data store emulator (with `gcloud` command-line tools) or the old style Datastore? What was your `dev_appserver.py` command and what’s your yaml?

Comment: These are my environment variables. export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8081/datastore. dev_appserver.py gives ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 2.7.x. I am using new cloud data store emulator. I am editing my question so that you can see my app.yaml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181552/discussion-between-salman-haseeb-sheikh-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 0):

The emulator simulates Cloud Datastore by creating /WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin in a specified data directory and storing data in local_db.bin. By default, the emulator uses the data directory ~/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/. You have to set needed environment variables, to use Datastore Emulator properly. Related detail is to be found on the "Running the Cloud Datastore Emulator" online documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#emulator_data_directories).